# XAMPP updates only one .js file of two upon Ctrl + F5

Tags: javascript, xampp, refresh

I have a page in development which links to two .js scripts.  When I tested it in XAMPP, it was not loading changes to either .js script.  Using Ctrl + F5 to reload the page causes it to notice my changes to the second script, but not my changes to the first.  What can I do to make it refresh both?

Comment: Maybe the other script is cached by the server?

Answer (score 0):

The extreme way is to add an `.htaccess` in your webroot folder.

In there you should add following lines:

```
# BEGIN Expire headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expire headers
```

But with this approach you will always load the javascrip file. For production use not recommended.